# How to create cover art for albums that are missing cover.jpg?

Tags: audio, mp3, tags, mpd

I have a bit of mixed bag music folders going on. Some have folder.jpg, some have cover.jpg and some do not have any album art in them but the songs have album art embed in the audio format. And some of my albums are missing cover art totally.

What I want is to create cover.jpg(or folder.jpg or album.jpg etc) for the album folders that are missing them as long as

- there could be at least one cover art in one of the audio files in the folder
- there is no cover art file in the album folder

My folders (generally) goes like this, which is typical I believe

Artist-> Album-> AudioFiles

So the final end point is really the album folder, and no need to get tags and recreate some folder structure.

I want to be able create the missing cover art in the album folder. And I want this cover art to come from the audio files in the folder. The first file  that has a cover art is fine with me. And the script should just exract the first hit in the folder no need for internet query etc.

To recap, I need this script to perform the steps below

- Recurse in to sub folders
- Look for cover art images, if there is one, move on to the next folder.
- If there is no cover art in the folder, look for an image in the audio files inside that album folder. Extract it and name it to cover.jpg If no oaudio file has any album art, create a text file called "MissingArt.txt" and proceed to the next folder.
- Never overwrite the existing cover images in the folder.
- Proceed to the next folder.

Yes I already use Picard but Picard is a bit of automatic and I have way too many audio files to deal with Picard that way.

I prefer the Linux solutions and I am ok with Windows solutions as well. I want to make my albums Mpd friendly.

thanks

Comment: Perhaps try https://picard.musicbrainz.org/ to do this on your behalf?

Comment: Did you read my entry? I already mentioned Picard.

Comment: I did read it, must not have registered however.